# Условие: если пользователь на странице своего профиля

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте.
Вывод профилей (они доступны всем посетителям для просмотра) производится через шаблон author.php.
Необходимо сделать условие: если авторизованный человек открыл страницу со своим профилем, то показать ему некий контент, если нет, то не показывать.
Была идея сравнивать ID автора страницы с ID зашедшим на неё юзером, но никак не могу условию сделать. Нужна помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну не совсем понятно, как у вас устроен шаблон. Каким образом определяется какого пользователя эта страница. Если стандартным, то скорее всего через GET строку. Тогда в шаблоне надо получить информацию о пользователе, чью страницу мы показываем:

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
```

В переменной $curauth мы будем иметь всю информацию о пользователе:

```
$curauth->aim;
$curauth->description;
$curauth->display_name;
$curauth->first_name;
$curauth->ID;
$curauth->jabber;
$curauth->last_name;
$curauth->nickname;
$curauth->user_email;
$curauth->user_login;
$curauth->user_nicename;
$curauth->user_registered;
$curauth->user_url;
$curauth->yim;
```

Теперь надо получить информацию об авторизованном пользователе:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Теперь можно писать условия:

```
    if($curauth->ID == $current_user->ID){
echo "secret information";
}
```

Comment: Начиная с версии 4.5, вордпресс осуждает [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) и рекомендует использовать [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user). Скорректируйте код в ответе, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то в шаблоне для вывода данных используется the_author_meta : имя, фамилия и т.д.
а страница формируется просто domen/author/nickname

Comment: Тогда такой способ должен вам подойти

Comment: да я уже затестил, действительно работает, спасибо.
хотя алгоритм - исходя из слага получить определить юзера и уже потом вытянуть данные)